# Django - Admin Interfaces - to allow create users for non-superuser

Tags: python, django, admin, roles, superuser

I have the situation of permits the access to admin interfaces to three types of users:
- Admin
- Supervisor
- Agent

It's a situation hierarchycal, the admin is one (the superuser) and it's creates the supervisors, and the supervisors create the agents.

All them can login to django admin with distincts authorizations.

The login has managed by 'django.contrib.auth' with the default model auth_user (.

```
     from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Supervisor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=60, db_column='E-Mail',blank=True)
   ...other fields....


class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=60, db_column='E-Mail',blank=True)
     ...other fields...
```

But, there is a problem. If I allow the supervisor to create an agent implies that I must add the authorization to ADD and CHANGE the table USER. And this is dangerous, any supervisors could become a superuser, deleting users, etc etc....

How can I resolve this problem?? Is it possible to permit the supervisor to create an Agent without that he can be dangerous??

Thanks

---

EDIT

I have a doubt... in models.py during a definition of class I written this method:

```
def save(self):
    self.user.is_staff = True
    self.user.save()
    super(Agent, self).save()
```

In Java, the method of EJB it was transactional/atomic (the commit is automatic)... In django, I have to call the method save().

It is a question different from the previous.....

Comment: I'll recommend that you read the documentation for permissions first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: For this I can't use the previous code ... I can't allow the ADD and CHANGE the AUTH_USER table

Comment: Furthermore, I have a doubt... the method def save(self) inside models.py during the definition of model class is a method atomic? The commit is automatic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got to understand your problem. But, if I did, you could edit the user creation form.

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    view_on_site = False
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', )
    fieldsets = (
        ('Data', {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')}),
        ('Activation/Deactivation', {'fields': ('is_active', )}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'groups', )})
)
```

As `superuser`is not an option anymore, your supervisors can't became superusers.

Let me know if this helps. Maybe we can get closer to the solution.

Comment: Mmmm... However they can always modify the data of the other supervisors, and of the other users present in the auth_user

Comment: Then override some of the admin site methods to hide other users from the list or change the form according to the user profile. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form),